# Creating NetRestore on 10.10.1 failing

Tags: macos

[image]When trying to create a NetRestore image in SIU on 10.10.1 and trying to add custom packages the build will always fail with Error Code 2.

I noticed when you try to Customize Packages that "Essential System Software" reads as 8.03TB but the SSD inside the computer is only 256GB.

I have tried to redownload the "Install OS X Yosemite" from the Mac App Store three times and with all 3 sources the "Essential System Software" will still always read as 8.03TB.

Does anyone else experience this and know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

'Customize Package Selection' is only valid for NetInstall images and not for NetRestore images - at least for Mavericks.

[Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH15674?viewlocale=en_US)

Probably it's the same for Yosemite. I haven't a source for that though.

On the other hand 'NetRestore' just uses an already prepared image of a working OS X installation - so absolutely nothing to customize afterwards...

Comment: Thats interesting. The Enterprise support guy at Apple seems to believe this should work and submitted the issue to the engineers